# /var/www/html/ is prepended to url

Tags: .htaccess

/var/www/html/ is prepended to url

I am writing rewrite url

```
RewriteRule /news-tags-wiki/(.*)$ /news_tags_wiki.php?tag=$1 [L]
```

but /var/www/html is prepended to url

http://34.236.128.251/var/www/html/news-tags-wiki/vijay/

also trailing slash in appended

Comment: I think you have an error in your virtual host.. Try checking where your DirectoryIndex points to

Comment: @Nicholas Nur but other redirects are working fine